# Корректность запятой и тире, где запятая отделяет сложноподчинённую часть предложения, а тире используется для обособления приложения

Tags: запятые

> <...>разработчики прибегают, помимо прочего, к использованию специальных программных средств — отладчиков, — которые автоматизируют наиболее монотонные аспекты ручной отладки

Слово «­­отладчиков» здесь является приложением, которое стоит в середине предложения и имеет пояснительный характер, и которое по этой причине обособляется тире (оно может быть обособлено и запятыми, полагаю, но автор выбрал именно тире).

Помимо этого, мы имеем сложное предложение со словом «­­который», которое должно отделяться запятой. Таким образом, здесь должны стоять и тире, и запятая.

Логика верна или нет? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ исправлен

Предлагаемый вариант неудобен для записи, так как там  два определения, расположенных рядом (приложение и определительное придаточное).

Это же содержание можно записать следующим образом: <...>***разработчики прибегают, помимо прочего, к использованию отладчиков – специальных программных средств, которые автоматизируют наиболее монотонные аспекты ручной отладки.***

Здесь использовано обособленное распространенное приложение в конце предложения.

**Примечание.** В авторском варианте приложение оформлено как вставная конструкция (пункт 4) http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#pp123

В этом случае используются **два тире**, а постановка запятых (одной или двух) делается по правилам. Здесь ставится только **вторая запятая**, так как вставка относится к первой части. Сравнить: *Он встал и, прихрамывая — он был на протезе, — подошёл к окну.*

Comment: С запятой возникает другой, неверный смысл: *тех отладчиков, которые...* Такое надо как-то устранять. Можно ли автоматизировать аспекты? Какое здесь словарное значение подходит (никакое)?

Comment: Здесь использован  термин. Аспект — логический объект в аспектно-ориентированном программировании, который позволяет объединять однотипные по функциональности элементы разных объектов.  https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Аспект

Comment: Тогда ещё хуже: *автоматизировать логические объекты*. Но там не это: *аспект в программировании ≠ аспект отладки*. Автоматизировать можно процесс/действие.

Comment: Так неправильно, так еще хуже, так вообще никуда не годится! Так напишите свой единственно правильный ответ. Или лучше не надо – все равно никто читать не будет и спасибо не скажет. Тогда какой смысл разговаривать с пустым залом.

Comment: Ну так у вас так получается, просто подставил значение.